# first request in axios not getting data back

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello I am using axios with react and and I have a problem with the first time requests. Every time my web has a full refresh then it is suppose to make two requests to the server:

1. to load the web global content
2. the child should load the current page related content

However, when I refresh the page, since the web global content is loaded in the `App.js` `compontDidMount`, then the global content is loaded, however for `HomePage.js` which in this case is the child component to `App.js` send the request in `compontDidMount` but checking the server logs, only the `option` handshake request is received and not the actual `get request` to get the page related content, however since am using `react-router-dom's` `Link` to navigate. If I navigate to another page then come back to home page then I get all the content since in that case the `App.js` `compontDidMount` will not be executed. could anyone help or explain why this is happening please

my `hoempage.js` `componentDidMount`
looks like this

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName="csrftoken"
axios.defaults.headers = get_headers()
axios.get(`${API_URL}/dns/`).then(res=>{
       this.setState({
           top6:res.data.top,
           latest:res.data.latest
        })
    })
```

my `App.js` `componentDidMount` is calling a functions in another file that uppdates redux and looks like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadGlobal();
}
```

`loadGlobal` looks like this

```
export const getGlobal = () => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getGlobalStart());
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
    axios.defaults.headers = get_headers();
    axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/get-global/`)
        .then(res => dispatch(getGlobalSuccess(res.data)))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message)
            dispatch(getGlobalFail(err.response.data))

        }).catch(err=>{
            dispatch(setAlert({ "show": true, error: true, "message":"network error fetching data, check your internet and try again or contact side admin if your network is fine"}))
        });
};
};
```

my `get_headers()` looks like this

```
function get_headers() {
   var headers = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
   };
  if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
     };
  }
  return headers
}
```

i my backend am using django which fetching data from postman or even visiting the url works just fine for me

Comment: Is there anyway I can reproduce this issue? This is not any special case, axios works well with multiple requests. So, there must be something wrong either in your frontend or backend code. Or maybe a CORS issue?

Comment: Yes. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you diagnose.

Comment: @AjeetShah i just added some code for my requets

Comment: @samuei hope that is helpful